# Java 7 update 25 silent installation fails if another version of java already exists

Tags: java, installshield

I am trying to install java from install shield script
1) I have no other version of Java in my PC and When I install Java 7 silently it installs correctly

2) If I have any other java version already installed in my PC and I try to install Java 7 silently it fails

Do we have an option to install java silently even though it detects another version of java is already installed?

Comment: Sadly the Java installers have lots of design defects.

Answer (score 0):

### Why is the install failing?

The first thing you should probably do is find out for sure why the JRE install is failing. 
The Windows version of it takes some [command-line parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/jre-installer-options.html) that may be of some use to you. For logging `/L <path_to_log>` will create a log file.

I usually extract the MSI from the EXE's that Oracle makes available. Using the MSI directly allows you to specify install properties without having to please InstallShield's goofy command-line syntax. If you launch the EXE downloaded from Oracle (but don't proceed—just let it extract itself), look in the user's `AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java` directory for a dir corresponding to the version of Java whose installer you just launched (e.g. `jre1.7.0_25`). Get the MSI and other files from there.

With the MSI, you can specify logging options on the command-line, like `msiexec /i <jre_msi_file> /lxv* C:\temp\jre_install.log`.

I'm pretty sure I've seen instances where JRE installers will effectively block the installation of an older ("less secure") version. It might be that this is what's happening in your case. You should see an indication of such in the install log file. If that's the case, I think there's a registry key that you can remove to "unblock" the install.

### Static vs. Patch-in-Place

Another potential source of trouble is the type of install you want (or previously used). Oracle has two install methods that you may need to [expressly specify](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/install/windows/patch-in-place-and-static-jre-installation.html#static) when you install it.

A patch-in-place install always leaves a single version of the JRE installed, removing the old one (or upgrading it—I'm not certain about the details of how it's done) and leaving the new one in its place. This is the default behavior, and is probably what you will want to use. Browsers can only use one version of Java at a time, so there's not much reason to have older versions around if you're only interested in having Java in the browser.

A static install creates a new install of Java for every unique version number. This would be useful if you needed to be able to choose among some precise versions of Java for specific applications. Programs relying on quirky/undocumented behavior of specific Java VM implementations might need to use such an installation. In general, though, this kind of thing should be avoided, if for no other reason, than to avoid leaving JRE versions with known (and actively exploited) security vulnerabilities.

You can specify which install type on the command-line with `STATIC=0` (a patch-in-place install) or `STATIC=1`. This should work with either the EXE or the MSI.